# Where can I get ADOMD library (DLL) to connect to Microsoft cubes using C#

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package, ssas-2012, adomd.net

I need to connect to Micrsoft SSAS (2012 server) cubes using C#. I want to know where can I get libraries (dll's) to connect to the cube?

Is there any nuget package to get the latest libraries or can i download the latest DLL from Microsoft site?

Comment: You probably already have it since it is included in the VS installer, navigate to c:\program files (x86)\microsoft.net\adomd.net.  If not then google "sql server 2012 feature pack".

Answer (score 1):

you can find the library file in C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\ADOMD.NET\100.You can install the same from nuget package Manager **Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient**